# Why does it take 33s to "head -1" a 250MB log file but "tail -1" is instantaneous?

Tags: linux, performance, nfs, btrfs

I'm trying to understand a weird behavior in my server. We share a btrfs volume over NFSv4 to the application servers. One of the apps will use a log file under this exported volume. logrotate will rotate it using copytruncate since the file remains open in the application.

Both "head" and "tail" commands were run on the NFS server which has the disk attached (all servers are on Google Cloud Platform, same region). "du" specifies the file has about 250MB.

Should truncate be avoided in btrfs volumes? What would explain such weird behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that outputting the first line was actually the issue:

```
head -1 file.log | wc -c

43297796
```

The first line was a long binary one for some reason.

```
time head -1 file.log > /dev/null
```

actually returned in 0.035s. I don't know what caused this line to become a binary one, but after figuring that out, the mystery was solved.

Comment: I'd say the cause was the file was truncated during a log rotation without telling the logging application which kept the file open. The application continues writting at the position it was before truncation, but all bytes before appear as null bytes and don't consume disk space. To check it, compare the output of `ls -lh file.log` with `du -h file.log`

Comment: I get the same size for both "ls -lh" and "du -h". But indeed it seems like they are null bytes as the output of "head -1" does not show any garbage. I see lots of "@" in Vim.

Comment: Perhaps it's something else entirely. But also perhaps NFS might not have handled sparse files as usual and the space was consumed